# Why do people ask drop rate questions?

Tags: discussion

What is the point of these questions? It's not like the person is going to stop running a dungeon trying to get the item. And it's all luck, the rate could be 50% but it's entirely possible to run a place 40 times and not get it.

Also usually exact drop numbers aren't available to the public anyway. I don't understand the point of these questions and why it is allowed. Could someone explain this so I can understand it better.

Edit: Assuming the question is about an item that can only drop from one place

Comment: Because they want to know? And the numbers can be gotten via research, which is often done within days of the game being released.

Comment: At the very least, knowing the odds allows people to gauge whether they think it's worth their time attempting to get the item. And a lot of the time, drop rates ARE available or can be derived: try something 100 times and unlock 10 items? That's pretty close to a 10% chance...

Comment: Yea they want to know but it's pointless because they will keep running the dungeon until they get it anyway. If someone needs an item for twinking for example in WOW, they will just keep going until they get it

Comment: @Huangism - not everybody. It also allows you to better prepare for the drop. For example, in Pokemon, you can get shiny Pokemon randomly in the wild, which have a different colouration & sparkle. They're very rare, should I spend my time endlessly farming for it? Probably not, as the drop rate is about 1/8192. I can also get them via breeding, with certain methods giving a 1/1024 and even 1/512 chance. So knowing the odds allows me to make choices that help me to choose how to approach the drop and unlock it faster

Comment: @Robotnik ok that applies when there are multiple places to get the same thing. I should of been more specific about the item dropping in one place only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People ask questions about drop rates of items for the simple reason that they would like to know an item's drop rate.

In addition to *just knowing* (which is enough for us to allow such questions), there are a variety of practical reasons to know an item's drop rate.

#### Best Method to Acquire

When there are multiple methods to acquire the same item, knowing the drop rates of the different methods can help a gamer decide which method is worth pursuing (most efficient).

#### Deciding Whether to Acquire

Although many gamers will go to almost any length to get the Infinity+1 Sword, there are many gamers that will not. Some gamers would like to know, on average, how much time acquiring such an item would take so they can decide whether they value that time higher than shiny pokémon.

#### Preparing for the Grind

Whether or not a gamer is willing to grind their way toward acquiring an item no matter the cost, it can be psychologically helpful to know just how long that grind is likely to take. If I spend several hours grinding for a rare item and I haven't gotten it, I might feel better knowing that the statistical likelihood was against it from the start.